# Completar número com "zeros" até que o tamanho total seja 9!

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Recebo por parâmetro um `Number`.. ex: 18 e preciso complementar ele com "zeros" até que o tamanho total seja de 9 números.. o resultado ficaria 180000000.

Se o valor recebido for 678 por exemplo, o resultado ficaria 678000000.

OBS: Caso o parâmetro recebido tiver 9 dígitos nada deve acontecer!

```js
let number = 18;
let count = number.toString().length;

for (let i = count; i < 9; i++) {
  number = number.toString() + '0';
}

number = parseInt(number);

console.log(number);
```

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma, existe alguma forma mais simples e performática de fazer o mesmo algoritmo?

Comment: E se não colocar zeros a direita, acaso o numero tenha mais de 9 digitos, ele ultrapassaria o limite de 9?

Comment: Não, ele nunca pode ultrapassar os 9 dígitos, caso o parâmetro recebido já venha com 9 dígitos.. nada deve acontecer!

Comment: Esse tipo de informação é importante, pois quando vi pensei que fosse o caso de "PAD" (right pad), mas então é exatamente. Por isso o importante é detalhar suas a pergunta desde o começo (e as **futuras perguntas** também)  para ajudar a ajudarmos com seus problemas.

Comment: Blzz vou editar aqui para adicionar essa informação!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mantendo a ideia de fazer com texto não precisa de um laço:

```js
let number = 18;
console.log(parseInt((number.toString() + '000000000').substring(0, 8)));
number = 678;
console.log(parseInt((number.toString() + '000000000').substring(0, 8)));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/ConcatOptions2.js).

A fórmula usada é para pegar a quantidade de dígitos que tem.

Se preferir só usar matemática (é o que eu prefiro já que transformar em texto é gambiarra se está querendo um número, por isso eu descararia o exemplo por texto, até porque ele é bem ineficiente para o intuito):

```js
let numero = 18;
console.log(numero * Math.pow(10, 8 - Math.log(numero) * Math.LOG10E + 1 | 0));
numero = 678;
console.log(numero * Math.pow(10, 8 - Math.log(numero) * Math.LOG10E + 1 | 0));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/ConcatOptions.js).

Eu não fiz uma verificação se a quantidade de dígitos já 9, porque este requisito não estava na pergunta original e porque ele parece errado ou pelo  menos incompleto, então precisaria ser melhor explicitado e se for só isso mesmo é só colocar um `if`, nada demais.

O Guilherme Nascimento fez um [teste que mostra que usando só matemática é absurdamente mais rápido](https://jsbench.me/g0k5s97920/). Eu até me surpreendi que o meu código manipulando *string* é o segundo mais rápido (muuuito atrás). Achei que o `padEnd()` seroa mais rápido, mas não foi, este método deve ser muito mal feito, ou então é escrito em JS mesmo, aí faria sentido ele ser mais lento. O teste não mostra a diferença entre o `for` e `while` como confrontado em uma resposta, mas deveria ser igual. Claro que depende de cada implementação, por isso teste em vários navegadores. No meu:

[image: Resultados mostrando diferença superior a 40x para a matemática, e uma pequena porcentagem nos demais]

Ele ainda fez a gentileza de [testar com Node para tirar a interferência que todo navegador oferece na performance](https://gist.github.com/brcontainer/e5bc89280f84d811b90738d6d52c1676), onde podemos ver que meu código de *string* foi mais que o sobro da velocidade das outras formas e a matemáticas deu quase 100x.

Eu notei que o teste ainda pode dar uma diferença maior. Porque a pergunta tem um ado numérico, então para fazer com *string* tem que fazer uma conversão que no teste já pegou feita. Essa conversão não é nada trivial, não é que vai aumentar 5% o tempo. O esforço deve quase dobrar o esforço necessário total, pelo menos em alguns casos. Imagine então ter quase 200x de diferença.

Eu percebo que muita gente não liga para isso. Embora esse caso não aconteça isso tão facilmente, tem casos que dá uma diferença brutal de custo, especialmente se usar nuvem. Tem caso que pode inviabilizar aplicação, a tal ponto que as pessoas começam procurar soluções mágicas quando fica muito lento, fazendo a aplicação muito pior porque não ligou pra performance onde importava. Eu já tive vários trabalhos que tive que resolver problemas de performance. Nunca fiz nada genial, só vi que o programador anterior era displicente com performance. Em geral obtinha ganhos que variavam de dezenas para milhares de vezes, e salvava a aplicação ou reduzia imensamente os custos, em geral eu gastava horas ou dias pra resolver isso.

Se quer algo curto jogue isso em uma função e use-a, mas não use algo desnecessário que tem uma performance tão pobre.

Comment: Legal brother! gostei das alternativas! Obrigado!

Answer (score 16):

Uma forma de fazer isso é usando o [`padEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd).

A função serve exatamente para o que está querendo fazer. Ela recebe como primeiro parâmetro a quantidade final de caracteres que a `String` deve ter e o conjunto de caracteres que vai preencher a `String` até o final.

```js
let number = 18;
let stringNumber = number.toString();
let newStringNumber = stringNumber.padEnd(9, '0');

console.log(parseInt(newStringNumber));
```

Comment: Votei +1, no entanto é valido dizer que o "pad" completa apenas, não limita, por fim acaba sendo necessário adicionar um substring de qualquer forma, pois conforme a necessidade do autor (tudo bem que ele, o autor da pergunta, esqueceu de detalhar) não pode passar de 9 dígitos, mas ainda sim a resposta vale como dica extra acaso outra pessoa chegue aqui.

Comment: Mas não ficou claro o conportamento que o AP deseja caso o número já tenha mais de 9 dígitos.

Comment: Foi exatamente o que eu falei, o autor esqueceu de detalhar, foi por este motivo que nem respondi a pergunta e só comentei https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/432376/completar-n%c3%bamero-com-zeros-at%c3%a9-que-o-tamanho-total-seja-9-javascript/432380?noredirect=1#comment836983_432376, pq a pergunta era ambigua, a culpa é do autor da pergunta, mas nestes casos de ambiguidade o melhor é confirmar primeiro com um comentário solicitando detalhes, porque no começo eu também pensei que se tratava de "PAD RIGHT" (em js padEnd) ... mas o meu +1 tá ai, viu? Pelo seu esforço ;)

Comment: Eu percebi que o seu comentário está relacionado a isso. Talvez no seu segundo comentário falta um **não**. Mas mesmo com ele eu ainda não sei o que deve acontecer caso o número recebido tiver mais de 9 dígitos.

Answer (score -1):

como vai?

Acredito que essa seja outra forma

```
function completar(num) {
    // Transformar em String antes de interar consome muito menos processamento.
    let number = String(num); 
    //Usar o while é mais eficiente nesse caso
    while(number.length < 9) { number += '0'; }

    return parseInt(number);
}

console.log(completar(678));
```

Boa sorte

Comment: Longe de mim querer criticar, mas preciso fazer um apontamento técnico, while não é mais eficiente, eu fiz um benchmark pra testar todas soluções e tanto no Firefox quanto no Chrome o `while` perdeu em eficiência para os demais, sendo que o que usa apenas substring foi o mais eficiente de fato, pode testar em seu navegador através do link: https://jsbench.me/g0k5s97920/ - qualquer duvida pode me "pingar" (escreva aqui `@guilherme`) ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento desconsiderando a matemática, né? Pq essa é a opção absurdamente mais eficiente. Pode por na minha resposta?

Comment: @Maniero pode adicionar diretamente se quiser, ou fala de comentar lá? No resumo creio que seja mais eficiente por estar trabalhando a string, se fosse operações matemáticas apenas provavelmente o resultado seria diferente mesmo, mas quando se trata de manipular "objetos" é bem provável que a maioria que APIs nativas resolvam um pouco mais rápido.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento por isso me surpreendeu o padend ser pior que o substring, o while eu tinha certeza que seria pior, pena que não comparou com o for, mas em tese é pra dar a mesma coisa na média

Comment: @Maniero provavelmente padEnd seja algo mal implementado ou que tenha uma série de regras e/ou avaliações internas que sejam necessárias e nem notemos. Fiz um benchmark local, com Node.js, só pra constar, neste caso Math foi incrivelmente superior: https://pastebin.com/raw/Rb11cT2U - seguido pelo `substring`. Vale lembra que Node.js usa o V8 e não pude comparar o motor do Firefox de forma standalone, se me lembro bem ele tem uma grande eficiência com cálculos, superava o v8

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pra mim deu no browser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT7TS.png No FF todas strings foram um pouco melhor que no Edge, mas matemática foi bem pior. No Chrome foram os piores resultados em tudo, mas matemática não foi muito pior.

Comment: @Maniero pode ser impressão minha, agora tive o mesmo resultado que o seu, nos outros testes eu troquei de aba, talvez seja algum gerenciamento de recurso do navegador, mas pode ter sido que olhei mal na hora (apesar de ter testado em 2 browsers)

Answer (score -2):

Post já foi resolvido mais vou deixar uma dica aqui par os novos que procurarem, existe um recurso no javascript que permite fazer esse trabalho facilmente.

```
string.padEnd(9, '0')
```

Qualquer string que não conter os 9 caracteres ele vai preencher no final dela com o dígito 0.

**links úteis:**

[Developer Mozilla PadEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd)

[Developer Mozilla PadStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Comment: Isso já foi dito [em outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/432380/100416)

Answer (score -3):

Não é a solução ideal, but...

```js
var boilerplate = "000000000000000000"
var numero = 23

var boilerplate = numero + boilerplate.substring(numero.toString().length, boilerplate.length);
console.log(boilerplate)
```

Comment: Não atende o caso..! =/